# How to create e_bar chart with both total and percentage in tooltip?

Tags: r, bar-chart, tooltip, echarts4r

In `echarts4r`, I am creating a tooltip that is to display both total and percentage. It works in pie or donut charts, but not in bar charts, which show *undefined%*. I have tried `totals += params.value[1]; perc = params.value[1] / totals;` in the bar chart `JS` function. But it does not work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)

My_df <- data.frame(n = c(2, 4, 10), 
                    x = c("A", "B", " C")) %>%
     mutate(percent = round(n/sum(n), 2) )
```

1. Donut chart:

```
My_df %>%
  e_charts(x)  %>% 
  e_pie(n, radius = c("50%", "70%")) %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                                        function(params){
                                        return('<strong>' + params.name + 
                                        '</strong><br/>total: ' + params.value + 
                                        '<br />percent: ' +  params.percent)  +'%' }  "))
```

[image]

2. Bar chart:

```
My_df %>%
  e_charts(x)  %>% 
  e_bar(n) %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                                        function(params){
                                        return('<strong>' + params.name + 
                                        '</strong><br/>total: ' + params.value[1] + 
                                        '<br/>percent: ' +  params.percent)  +'%' }  "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that for `e_pie` the percentage value is computed by `echarts` under the hood and added as an attribute to the `params` object (Put differently: There is no need to compute the percentage value manually for a pie chart and actually the `percent` column of your data is not used). But this is not the case for `e_bar`. Hence, `params.percent` is `undefined` as there is not attribute with name `percent`.

However, one possible hack would be to pass the `percent` value via the `bind` parameter which is then stored in the `name` attribute, whereas the category value mapped on `x` can be retrieved from the `value` array, i.e. `value[0]`:

```
library(echarts4r)

My_df |> 
  e_charts(x) |> 
  e_bar(n, bind = percent) |> 
  e_tooltip(
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
      function(params) {
        return('<strong>' + params.value[0] +
        '</strong><br/>total: ' + params.value[1] +
        '<br/>percent: ' +  100 * params.name)  +'%' 
      }")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can also try using `e_add_nested`. Here you can pass additional variables in your data other than the ones already being mapped.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)

My_df %>%
  e_charts(x)  %>% 
  e_bar(n) %>%
  e_add_nested('extra', percent) %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
              function(params) {
                return('<strong>' + params.name + 
                '</strong><br/>total: ' + params.value[1] + 
                '<br/>percent: ' +  params.data.extra.percent)  +'%' 
              }
            "))
```

[image: e_bar figure with percent]

Comment: Ui. An even better and less hacky option which also allows to pass multiple values.

Comment: Thanks, @stefan and @Ben! Both methods work well. It seems that `e_add_nested` gives a little more flexibility since more parameters can be added as 'extra'.